# Using cURL, jq, and declaration and for loop condition, I tried to download multiple files from a GitLab private repo, but it downloaded only one

Tags: bash, curl, for, gitlab, declare

I learned from the following sources:

- **`curl -O`**: [Download a file with curl on Linux / Unix command line](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/download-a-file-with-curl-on-linux-unix-command-line/)
- **jq:** [How to urlencode data for curl command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/296536/how-to-urlencode-data-for-curl-command/34407620#34407620)
- **Multiple files and `curl -J`:** [download pdf files from using curl](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/91798/download-pdf-files-from-using-curl)
- **Condition `for` loop:** [Shell: how to use 2 variables with for condition](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/377446/shell-how-to-use-2-variables-with-for-condition) and [Unable to download data using curl for loop](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/291049/unable-to-download-data-using-curl-for-loop)

Description of the script:

1. Variables, required by GitLab's [Repository files API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/repository_files.html):

   ```bsh
   branch="master"
   repo="my-dotfiles"
   private_token="XXY_wwwwwx-qQQQRRSSS"
   username="gusbemacbe"
   ```
2. I used a declaration for multiple files:

   ```bsh
   declare -a context_dirs=(
     "home/.config/Code - Insiders/Preferences"
     "home/.config/Code - Insiders/languagepacks.json"
     "home/.config/Code - Insiders/rapid_render.json"
     "home/.config/Code - Insiders/storage.json"
   )
   ```
3. I used the condition `for` loop with `jq` to convert all files from the declaration `context_dirs` to encoded URLs:

   ```bsh
   for urlencode in "${context_dirs[@]}"; do
     paths=$(jq -nr --arg v "$urlencode" '$v|@uri')
   done
   ```
4. I used the condition `for` loop to download with `curl` multiple files taken from `paths` converted by `jq`. It is important that I used `-0` and `-J` to output the file name, and `-H` for `"PRIVATE-TOKEN: $private_token"`:

   ```bsh
   for file in "${paths[@]}"; do 
       curl -sLOJH "PRIVATE-TOKEN: $private_token" "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/$username%2F$repo/repository/files/$file/raw?ref=$branch"
   done
   ```

Complete source code:

```bsh
branch="master"
id="1911000X"
repo="my-dotfiles"
private_token="XXY_wwwwwx-qQQQRRSSS"
username="gusbemacbe"

declare -a context_dirs=(
  "home/.config/Code - Insiders/Preferences"
  "home/.config/Code - Insiders/languagepacks.json"
  "home/.config/Code - Insiders/rapid_render.json"
  "home/.config/Code - Insiders/storage.json"
)

for urlencode in "${context_dirs[@]}"; do
  paths=$(jq -nr --arg v "$urlencode" '$v|@uri')
done

for file in "${paths[@]}"; do 
    curl -sLOJH "PRIVATE-TOKEN: $private_token" "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/$username%2F$repo/repository/files/$file/raw?ref=$branch"
done
```

But the two conditions `for` loop output only an encoded path and downloaded only a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first loop overwrites the value of the variable `paths` in each iteration.  Since you later expect this to be an array, make sure it is created properly:

```
paths=()
for urlencode in "${context_dirs[@]}"; do
  paths+=( "$(jq -nr --arg v "$urlencode" '$v|@uri')" )
done
```

Alternatively, combine the two loops:

```
for urlencode in "${context_dirs[@]}"; do
  file=$(jq -nr --arg v "$urlencode" '$v|@uri')
  curl -sLOJH "PRIVATE-TOKEN: $private_token" "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/$username%2F$repo/repository/files/$file/raw?ref=$branch"
done
```

Comment: What if `-o "$HOME/Vídeos/"`?

Comment: @GustavoReis Sorry, I don't quite understand the question. The `-o` option of `curl` takes the name of the output file to write to, not a directory name.

Comment: `curl -sLOJH -o "$HOME/Vídeos/"`. I need to send the files to the specific folder (`-o`) without giving output name (therefore, `-O` will do it). Maybe better `cd "$HOME/Vídeos"; curl -sLOJH"`, but I will send different files to different specific folders.

Comment: @GustavoReis If you want to use `-O`, then you have to `cd` to the correct directory first, this is actually mentioned in the `curl` manual, in the description of the `-O` option. This is also outside of the scope of you original question.

Comment: Sorry, I wanted to use `--create-dirs` to create the directories from the URLs hierarchy, for example: `cd "$HOME/Vídeos"; curl -sLOJ -H "PRIVATE-TOKEN: $private_token" "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/$username%2F$repo/repository/files/$file/raw?ref=$branch" --create-dirs`, and `--create-dirs` will create `"home/.config/Code - Insiders/`. But it did not work.

Comment: @GustavoReis As mentioned in the manual, `--created-dirs` only works with `-o` and will create the directories mentioned in the output filename if they don't already exist.

Comment: Ah, I tried with `curl -sL -J --create-dirs -o -H` and nothing worked.

Comment: @GustavoReis The `-o` option takes an argument, the pathname of the output file. The command that you show seems to want to create a file called `-H`.

Comment: Then I also tried `curl -sLJ --create-dirs -o "$HOME/Vídeos/" -H` or `curl -sLJ -o "$HOME/Vídeos/" --create-dirs  -H`

Comment: @GustavoReis The `-o` option of `curl` takes the name of the output file to write to, not a directory name.

Comment: Too bad, is there some solution? Sorry for not adding extra example about creating automatically directories based on URL hierarchy in my question. Should I update my question?

Comment: @GustavoReis You may want to ask a separate question about this. I don't usually answer follow-up questions in comments, and it's a separate issue from what your current question asks about.

Comment: OK, done. Closed.